# In Programmed I/O transfer How Does the cpu know when to do I/O operation if it doesn't support interrupt facility?

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture

If Programmed I/O doesn't support Interrupt facility then how does the CPU know when to perform I/O transfer ?. Doesn't it mean that CPU will always keep executing the memory instruction without knowing the I/O wants to execute its instruction because there is no concept of interrupt. If there was interrupt then the CPU could execute the I/O instruction as well. please help

Thanks

Comment: The CPU itself doesn't care. It's up to the program or device driver doing the I/O to poll if the device is ready or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your system doesn't support interrupts, and only has PIO (Programmed IO) then you need to make sure that driver software of the IO devices periodically check to see to if they needs any data transfer being done. If so, CPU will perform the transfer operations as specified in the PIO.

Comment: What do you mean by PIO program ?

Comment: Typically this would be the driver software of the IO device. Anyway thanks for the question, clarified my answer

Comment: It could be stored in your hard disk and loaded into memory which CPU will run periodically.

Comment: okay got it thanks brother. btw what do you mean by "thanks for question.." what question you pointing to ?

Comment: I meant the question in your first comment. I was using confusing terminology in my first version of the answer and your comment made me fix it.